# Is it possible that I find a number from 2 informations then I try of the number work and it dosent?

Tags: proof-explanation

Imagine I got 2 conditions or informations to find a unknown number x and did many steps ( of course mathematically correct with no mistake) using both conditions to find a value of x. Is it possible, to replace x and see it not work for any reason?
Example:
We get two equations with unknowns
we use the substition method and get x
and then we get and y
with all mathematically valid steps
and then we see that these y and x does not valid both equations.Can this happen? and can we get a false value of x;y when the system has no solutions?

Comment: If you preserve the domain for each operation, the situation you describe cannot happen. Post a concrete example if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

If all steps were mathematically valid, and if you are interpreting each mathematical step correctly, then you should always see the result working.  If not, you are probably violating a mathematical assumption, or you are missing another piece of information, or you are misinterpreting the result.

To answer your specific example, we are given 2 equations.  I will break it up into cases:

$1)$ There are less than 2 unknowns.  In this case, you can always find a solution and *it will always work*

$2)$ There are 2 unknowns.  In this case, you you can either (a) find infinitely many solutions (b) find finitely many solutions (c) find that there are no solutions.  Your solutions *will always work*

$3)$ There are more than 2 unknowns.  In this case, it is generally impossible to find solution.  But you may be able to get a partial answer in terms of the other unknowns, or find that the problem can be reduced to 2 unknowns and hence solveable

Comment: added an example

Comment: The question is still very general, but my answer covers most cases